# Unable to add a new line in default text responses

Tags: dialogflow-es

I know this is a very dumb question and that the dialogflow documentation clearly states that to add a new line in a default text response, all I have to do is press Shift+Enter but for some reason it just doesn't seem to work in the output.

[image: This is what's happening]

I've been at this for 30 mins now. Someone please help me out.

Comment: To get this right, you can create inline in the dialogflow, but in response you got only `this is line 1` response instead of `this is line 1 <br> this is a new line after pressing(shift+enter)`? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I guess you are using `Dialogflow Web Demo`

Answer (score 0):

As I mention, I guess you are using [Dialogflow Web Demo](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/web-demo)

> This integration **only supports single text responses**. Rich messages (including sequential text responses, line breaks, hyperlinks, images etc) **are not supported**.
>
> ...
>
> To use rich **response messages** and **customizations**, see the **Dialogflow Messenger** integration.

In documentation [Quickstart: Interactions with an integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/integration) you can find steps how to use `Integration`.

This is my response settings:

[image]

and one of my `Training phrases` are `hey`, `hello`, and few others.

On the left side, you have `Integrations`. When you scroll down a bit, you will find `Text based`.
If I will use `Web Demo` I will get only one line:

[image]

However, if I will use `Dialogflow Messenger` (which is still beta) it works as expected.
[image]